# Android Tool Window not found in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea

IntelliJ documentation and other stackoverflow answers say that the Android Tool Window should be under the `View --> Tool Windows` menu, but it is not available there for me in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 (latest version as of this writing). I also tried disabling then re-enabling the Android plug-in and restarting. How can it be opened?

Comment: Actually IntelliJ 2016.1 is the latest version as of your question, but I see that option just fine my IntelliJ.

Comment: woops you're right, and I do have 2016.1; i just remembered the wrong/old name. thanks. editing the question... Do you have 15? I wonder why I can't see it. Perhaps it could have to do with my project particulars?: a gradle, multi-module project, using jfxmobile plugin in the main app module